# Turn off “parent in place”?

Tags: parent

Right now, when I parent an object to another object, the child remains in its original place. Is there a way to “turn this off” and have the child instantly snap to the position and rotation of its parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "(Object) Keep Transform" variant of parenting when you hit Ctrl+P.  Then just zero the locations/rotations of the child object.

Comment: A variant to this, would be to Select the Parent Object, and set your cursor there (Shift+S >> Cursor to Active). Then select your Child Object (Shift+S >> Selection to Cursor). Then Parent the Child normally.  This would be a similar approach to this answer, but it would not require the user to track X,Y,Z as the selections and cursor would accomplish this purpose, but effectively does the same thing.